# Fastest way to move a sparsebundle?

Tags: network-attached-storage, transfer

I've got a +900GB sparsebundle on one HDD that I'm trying to transfer to a NAS. Since the sparsebundle is essentially a folder, I've been using `rsync` but it's so damn slow! What's the fastest way to move it off that hard drive and on to the NAS?

**Or** is there a way to tell `rsync` to resume from a certain point, e.g.: don't bother start from band/0, start from band/x?

Comment: If you're running `rsync` with the `-t` or `-a` options it should figure out which files on the destination are up to date based on the timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I had another go and wrote a shell script. I figured that if I queried the destination folder to see what the last file was then I can run a loop and pick off from where I left off:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
matched=false
last=$(ls /destination/folder | tail -1)

for file in /source/folder/*
do
    name=${file/\/source\/folder\//}

    if [ $matched = true ]; then
        cp -Rv "$file" /destination/folder/
    else
        if [ $name = $last ]; then
            matched=true
        fi
    fi
done
```

Yep I know I should declare some more vars for the source and destination, but it works and it's not bad for 2mins work!